# Cannot install pycosat on alpine during dockerizing

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, alpine-linux

I am trying to dockerize django application, and I am using **alpine:edge** as base image. And **pycosat** installation fails with error

```
In file included from pycosat.c:19:
picosat.c:8150:10: fatal error: sys/unistd.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/unistd.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Here how is my Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM alpine:edge
    ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1

    RUN apk update && \
        apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
        libffi-dev openssl-dev python3 py3-zmq build-base libzmq zeromq-dev \
        curl g++ make zlib-dev linux-headers openssl ca-certificates libevent-dev

    RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools
    RUN mkdir /config
    ADD /config/requirements.txt /config/
    RUN easy_install pyzmq
    RUN easy_install pycosat
    RUN mkdir /src
    WORKDIR /src
```

How can I make it to install this lib? Do I miss some packages or utils or something?

Also I am using docker-compose to build it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems pycosat is not compatible with musl, the libc library implementation used in Alpine.

musl's `unistd.h` header is located at the system headers root folder,  `/usr/include`, and not under `/usr/include/sys` as in glibc (glibc is the defacto Linux libc standard), and therefore compilation fails with `fatal error: sys/unistd.h: No such file or directory`.

As a workaround, you could create your own header under `sys/unistd.h` which will simply include the native `unistd.h`, prior to pycosat build step:

```
RUN echo "#include <unistd.h>" > /usr/include/sys/unistd.h
```